# Do squats make your butt hard

Tags: squats

[image]
Can doing squats make your butt hard since you're developing muscles there

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with an asterisk.

Sure, since muscle is more dense than fat, increasing muscle mass (glutes) and decreasing fat in your butt will serve to harden it.

[image]

**The asterisk**

I feel a need to point out that while squatting activates the glutes, there are exercises that do more for them than a regular squat, such as the deadlift. So if one of your goals is to get a firmer butt, I would suggest focusing more on deadlifting. The squat is still a great exercise though, and shouldn't be forgotten either.